# move selected items from a listbox to another using dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, listbox

[image]

I have two listboxes.the left one is bound from this code and the values goes to a dictionary:

```
    public void Roster_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Basketball;Integrated Security=True;User ID=apo;Password=nia2");
        con.Open();   
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PLAYERS.ID, PLAYERS.NO, PLAYERS.SURNAME, PLAYERS.FIRSTNAME, CAST(PLAYERS.NO AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + PLAYERS.SURNAME + ', ' + PLAYERS.FIRSTNAME AS PLAYER FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN TEAMS ON PLAYERS.TEAM_ID = TEAMS.ID WHERE (TEAMS.NAME ='" + ht + "')ORDER BY PLAYERS.NO", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            listBox1.DataSource = dt;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "PLAYER";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

            dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                dictionary.Add(dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["PLAYER"].ToString()); 
 con.Close();
     }
```

I want to move the selected items to the second(right listbox2) using this dictionary.The "ID" is tha value and the "PLAYER" is the shown text. I want to use two buttons.One to send items to the right listbox2 and one to move back the selected items to the first listbox1.

Any suggestion?A Try the follow code but is not working.ADD() is the class for moving items and REMOVE() is for move back the items.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ADD();
    }
    private void ADD()
    {
        listBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(Roster_Shown.dictionary, null);
        listBox2.DisplayMember = "ID";
        listBox2.ValueMember = "PLAYER";
    } 

   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        REMOVE();
    }
    private void REMOVE()
    {
        int c = listBox2.Items.Count - 1;

        for (int i = c; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (listBox2.GetSelected(i))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(listBox2.Items[i]);
                listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Image shows the result using the code from Dmitry]
Image shows the result using the code from Dmitry,but I need to show only the text and to save somewhere the id(maybe in an arraylist or dictionary) because I will need to get all the ids of the second list and transfer them to a new listbox in another winform

Adding the following code to Dmitry's code the app is working perfect.

```
     public void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (listBox2.Items.Count > 4)
        {
            if (listBox4.Items.Count > 4)
            {

                Game game = new Game();

                foreach (ListItem item in listBox2.Items)
                { 
                    dictionaryHome.Add(item.Id, item.Name);
                    game.listBoxHome.DisplayMember = dictionaryHome.Values.ToString();
                    game.listBoxHome.ValueMember = dictionaryHome.Keys.ToString();
                    game.listBoxHome.DataSource = (from Values in    dictionaryHome.Values select Values).ToList();

                    //int itemId = item.Id;
                }
     this.Hide();

                game.Show();

            }
        }
       }
```

with button7 a new listbox in a new form takes all the items from listbox2(right one)and have both id(key) and value.Many thanks to Dmitry!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When the `DataSource` property is set, a user cannot modify the items collection.

Try this sample code:

```
internal sealed class TwoListsForm : Form
{
    private sealed class ListItem : IComparable<ListItem>
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;

        public int CompareTo(ListItem other)
        {
            return other == null ? 1 : Id.CompareTo(other.Id);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lstLeft;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lstRight;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnToRight;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnToLeft;

    public TwoListsForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TwoListsForm(string ht)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Basketball;Integrated Security=True;User ID=apo;Password=nia2"))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT PLAYERS.ID, PLAYERS.NO, PLAYERS.SURNAME, PLAYERS.FIRSTNAME, CAST(PLAYERS.NO AS VARCHAR) + ' - ' + PLAYERS.SURNAME + ', ' + PLAYERS.FIRSTNAME AS PLAYER FROM PLAYERS INNER JOIN TEAMS ON PLAYERS.TEAM_ID = TEAMS.ID WHERE (TEAMS.NAME ='" + ht + "')ORDER BY PLAYERS.NO", con))
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);

                object[] items = new object[dt.Rows.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    items[i] = new ListItem { Id = (int)dt.Rows[i]["ID"], Name = dt.Rows[i]["PLAYER"].ToString() };
                lstLeft.Items.AddRange(items);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.lstLeft = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.lstRight = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.btnToRight = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.btnToLeft = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // lstLeft
        // 
        this.lstLeft.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.lstLeft.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.lstLeft.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.lstLeft.Name = "lstLeft";
        this.lstLeft.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        this.lstLeft.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 264);
        this.lstLeft.Sorted = true;
        this.lstLeft.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // lstRight
        // 
        this.lstRight.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.lstRight.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.lstRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(341, 12);
        this.lstRight.Name = "lstRight";
        this.lstRight.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        this.lstRight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 264);
        this.lstRight.Sorted = true;
        this.lstRight.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // btnToRight
        // 
        this.btnToRight.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.btnToRight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(260, 77);
        this.btnToRight.Name = "btnToRight";
        this.btnToRight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnToRight.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnToRight.Text = ">>>";
        this.btnToRight.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnToRight.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnToRight_Click);
        // 
        // btnToLeft
        // 
        this.btnToLeft.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.None;
        this.btnToLeft.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(260, 180);
        this.btnToLeft.Name = "btnToLeft";
        this.btnToLeft.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.btnToLeft.TabIndex = 3;
        this.btnToLeft.Text = "<<<";
        this.btnToLeft.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnToLeft.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnToLeft_Click);
        // 
        // TwoListsForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(595, 290);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnToLeft);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnToRight);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lstRight);
        this.Controls.Add(this.lstLeft);
        this.Name = "TwoListsForm";
        this.Text = "Two Lists Form";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }

    private void btnToRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveItems(lstLeft, lstRight);
    }

    private void btnToLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        moveItems(lstRight, lstLeft);
    }

    private void moveItems(ListBox from, ListBox to)
    {
        if (from.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty selection");
            return;
        }
        object[] tmp = new object[from.SelectedItems.Count];
        from.SelectedItems.CopyTo(tmp, 0);
        to.Items.AddRange(tmp);
        from.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (var item in tmp)
            from.Items.Remove(item);
        from.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (TwoListsForm frm = new TwoListsForm(/* Your ht value */))
    frm.Show();
```

Get IDs of the right listbox items:

```
foreach (ListItem item in lstRight.Items)
{
    int itemId = item.Id;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Items appearance corrected.
**EDIT2:** Get items IDs added.

Comment: Yes this is working.This will move items as it shown in the new image. I want to show only the text and to save the ID somewhere else.Maybe in an arraylist or dictionary because I will need a new button to take all ids and transfer them to a new listbox in another winform.

Comment: Sample updated. The only change is in the `ListItem.ToString` method. Now only the text will be displayed.

Comment: Thanks.Now is it possible to get all the IDs of the listbox 2 and fill a new listbox in another winform?

Comment: Sure! Just cast each of them to the `ListItem` type. I've updated the answer. To be able to share `ListItem`s between forms, make it public.

Comment: Thank you very much Dmitry.Is working as you told me.